# store the number of button clicks asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, click, increment

I have given the user the option to download images that are being uploaded by a provider. When the download button is clicked the image downloads. **But I also want to store how many times that download button is clicked.**
For that I typed this code, but it isn't working.

I tried several ways like declaring an int variable and increment it. Didn't work. Then I tried this. Still not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
 protected void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var res = (byte[])Session["Image"];

           Response.Clear();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(res);
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Image.jpg");
            Response.Buffer = true;
            ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();



            try
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [ImageWithTags] SET DownloadCount = DownloadCount + 1 WHERE ImageID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con);
                con.Open(); 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }




        }
```

Comment: What error (if any) are you getting? What happens when you debug it?

Comment: no error comes. it just doesnt store the download count in the database

Comment: If you put your break point on `con.Open()`, then look at your `command` variable, is your query what you would expect it to be?

Comment: you can use a [Viewstate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) or [Session variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: How about doing the SQL command BEFORE the response.end?

Comment: Oh: and how about using a SQL parameter instead of concatenation - that is an opening for an injection attack.

Comment: I tried SQL parameters, doing the SQL command before respond.end still nothing happens.

Comment: Why dont u create a column in sql and insert 0 at the first time and then when user downloads the image, fetch the value, increment it and then update it.

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL Profiler?  Would be interesting to see if the command makes it to SQL (and what it looks like)

Comment: something doesn't look right with WHERE ImageID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'" - could it be SelectedItem.Value? because Text and ImageID  doesn't seem like a good match

Answer (score -1):

You can create a session variable for that as well and do the calculations like:

```
protected void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter=0;    
    if(Session["counter"]!=null)
     {
        Session["counter"] = ++Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"]);
        counter = Convert.ToInt32Session["counter"];
     }
    else
      Session["counter"] = 0;
        // do your calculation here with variable counter
}
```

Comment: He is not wanting to store how many times the button is pressed in the session, but on the site across all users.